# Moderncv theorem environment error

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, moderncv, texshop

I am using the following research statement template.  In my statement, I have to use the environment of the theorem, lemma, definition. It is giving me error when I am compiling my LaTeX file. I could not find the error. Any help appreciated.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (9/12/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the moderncv.cls and .sty files to be in the same
% directory as this .tex file. These files provide the resume style and themes
% used for structuring the document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
%\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}


%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%\newtheorem{specialthm}{specialthm}
%\renewcommand*{\thespecialthm}{\arabic{specialthm}}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{} % Your first name
\familyname{} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
%\title{Research Statement}
%\address{}{}
%\mobile{()}
%\phone{(000) 111 1112}
%\fax{(000) 111 1113}
%\email{}
%\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
%\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{pictures/picture} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
%\quote{"A witty and playful quotation" - John Smith}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle % Print the CV title
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Previous Research Experience}
\begin{theorem}
Hello new
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
\end{lemma}

{\hskip 2em}  


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Research Goals}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Latex tells you very clearly why there is an error. This is because there is no section counter defined, simply because this class does not have the usual sections. So one thing you could do is to use `\newcounter{section}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}`  instead of `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`.

Comment: Which version of `moderncv` do you use (check the log file for the version number!). Your used template is a little bit outdated  (2012)...

Comment: Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter d
ocument class

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Please let me know if there is a newer version.

Comment: The command \cref do not work in this moderncv?

Answer (score 1):

The current version 2.0 of class `moderncv` is **simply not prepared to handle** theorems, corrolary or lemmas, `\ref` and `\cref`.

It is a special class only designed for CVs and not big documents containing theorems, refs or crefs ... If you really need theorems in an cv (I really doubt that!) use another, better suited class for this, for example `article` or `scrartcl`.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I don't need theorem in my cv but I do need the abstracts of many things. Was this problems solved within moderncv?